# Visual Studio doesnt find the installed .net SDK

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dotnet-sdk

I have correctly installed the .Net SDK (Version 7) and in the "Program Files" folder it was shown.
But when I start Visual Studio, it didnt find it and the Project-Map on the rightsight is empty.

Visual Studio Version 2022 is used.

A short instruction to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had this problem before, my solution:

1. close all vs-apps
2. go to your Advanced System Settings -->
   Advanced --> Environment Variables
3. Under System Variables you
   will find the entry "Path" --> edit this one
4. move the "C:\Program
   Files\dotnet" entry on top of "C:\Program Files(x86)\dotnet"
5. press ok and
   restart vs

hope that resolves the issue

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who isn't fixed by the accepted answer, another possibility is that you don't have an updated version of Visual Studio 2022. You must be >= 17.5 to support .NET 7.0.

Comment: Ah, this was the real issue!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you because I didn't expect it to be a problem until it was.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with macOS, here is the answer that saved me from Microsoft Team, which might apply to windows as well:

> Hi, unfortunately Visual Studio for Mac needs you to specify the full path to the dotnet cli executable, not the directory, in Preferences - Build and Debug - SDK Locations - .NET Core - .NET Core Command line:
> `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet`

Indeed I've tried to add `/usr/local/share/dotnet/` or `/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk` but forgot to try `/usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet` duh.